# JAVA .equalsIgnoreCase not working

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

In the main method of my server class I have a series of `if` statements for the reserved keywords of a chat program which I am trying traverse using the value of a variable along with the `.equalsIgnoreCase` method. The problem is that even though my variable holds a certain value, when executing the program the code always steps into the `else` clause even if there is an exact match between the variable and one of the `if` conditions. The code compiles fine but I just cant figure out why this is happening. I have printed the value of the variable just before commencing the `if` statements to verify it held the correct value. A snipet from my code is shown below:

```
System.out.println("Keyword is : " + keyword);
if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("who")) 
{  
  System.out.println("calling who function");
  whoFunction(address, socket, port);
} 
else if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("whoami")) 
{ 
  whoami(address, socket, port, clientAddress);
} 
else if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) 
{   
  all(message);
} 
else if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("Bye")) 
{
  bye(address, socket, port, clientAddress);
} 
else 
{     
  newUser(keyword, address, searchListLength, clientAddress, port);
}
```

No matter what the value of the keyword is, it always resorts to selecting the final else statement. As you can see this will result in always call my `newUser` class. Am I missing something here? Probably staring me in the face :/

Comment: Could it be possible that your `keyword` string contains trailing `null` or other non-printable characters making the `equalsIgnoreCase` fail to detect a match?

Comment: Always print the values or use the debugger in such a case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that the String `keyword` does not contain any trailing newline/spaces or other nonprintable characters?

Answer (score 7):

There could be leading/trailing spaces in your input, which would cause a non-match.

Try adding this statement at the top:

```
keyword = keyword.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see Collator

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison. You
>   use this class to build searching and sorting routines for natural
>   language text.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html
- [Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html)